pyside6 How to continuously display output in a textbox in real-time
I want to use a for loop to display numbers from 0 to 4 in a textbox in sequence. However, the output is displayed all at once after the loop finishes. I don't know how to make it display in real-time.
I have tried searching on Google and testing QThread multiple times, but I couldn't solve the problem.
GUI.py
class WorkerThread(QThread):
    update_signal = Signal(str) 

    def run(self):
        temp = test.guiTest()
        self.update_signal.emit(temp)
        time.sleep(0.2)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

def pb_test_click(self):
        
        self.worker = WorkerThread()
        self.worker.update_signal.connect(self.update_label)
        
        self.start_thread()
        self.testPrint()

    def testPrint(self):
        for i in range(5):
            temp = str(i)
            self.text_log.appendPlainText(temp)
            time.sleep(0.2)
        return temp

    
    def start_thread(self):
        if not self.worker.isRunning():  
            self.worker.start()

    def update_label(self, message):
        self.text_log.appendPlainText(message)

I want to use a for loop to display numbers from 0 to 4 in a textbox in sequence. However, the output is displayed all at once after the loop finishes. I don't know how to make it display in real-time.

Use QTimer, Using time.sleep() completely blocks everything and it's wrong to use such things in the UI thread, especially in a loop.

See also: Use PyQt's QThread to Prevent Freezing GUIs.
